# Ruby internals and how to guarantee unique hash values

Tags: ruby, hash, hashmap, murmurhash

Hash in Ruby just uses its hash value (for strings and numbers). Internally, it uses [the Murmur hash function](http://preshing.com/20110504/hash-collision-probabilities/). I wonder **how it can can be done given that the probability of having the same hash value for two different keys is not zero**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you share with us how you came to the conclusion that Ruby uses *only* the hash value to determine equality?

The text below is to explain to others your excellent point that **the probability of computing the same hash value for two different keys is not zero**, so how can the Hash class rely on just the hash value to determine equality?

For the purpose of this discussion I will refer to Ruby *hashes* as *maps*, so as not to confuse the 2 uses of the term *hash* in the Ruby language (1, a computed value on an object, and 2, a map/dictionary of pairs of values and unique keys).

As I understand it, hash values in maps, sets, etc. are used as a quick first pass at determining *possible equality*.  That is, if the hashes of 2 objects are equal, then it is *possible* that the 2 objects are equal; but it's also possible that the 2 objects are not equal, but coincidentally produce the same hash value.

In other words, the only sure thing you can tell about equality from the hash values of the objects being compared is that if hash1 != hash2 then the objects are definitely not equal.

If the 2 hashes *are* equal, then the 2 objects must be compared by their content (in Ruby, by calling the `==` method, I believe).

So comparing hashes is not a *substitute* for comparing the objects themselves, it's just a quick first pass used to optimize performance.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that a "hash table" or dictionary is perfectly okay with collisions. In fact, it's expected and accommodated in any reasonable implementation.

Ideally you strive to have a hash with as few collisions as possible, and there are entire doctoral level discussions on what makes a good hashing function, but they are inevitable. When a collision does occur then two values share the same index in the container.

Regardless of how a value is hashed, any *potential* match based on hash must be evaluated. A direct comparison is performed to ensure that the value you're accessing is the one requested, not one that coincidentally maps to the same spot.

Normal hash tables can be thought of as an array of arrays even though this is all completely hidden from you in general purpose use.

You can implement your own hash table in Ruby if you want to explore how this behaves:

```
class ExampleHash
  include Enumerable

  def initialize
    @size = 9
    @slots = Array.new(@size) { [ ] }
  end

  def [](key)
    @slots[key.hash % @size].each do |entry|
      if (entry[0] == key)
        return entry[1]
      end
    end

    nil
  end

  def []=(key, value)
    entries = @slots[key.hash % @size]

    entries.each do |entry|
      if (entry[0] == key)
        entry[1] = value

        return
      end
    end

    entries << [ key, value ]
  end
end
```

This is made easy since every object in Ruby has a built-in `hash` method that produces a large numerical value that's based on the object's content.